# mongoose : findByIdAndUpdate through erro "message":"Cast to string failed for value \"undefined\"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have `Item` model,

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String, es_indexed:true},
    price: Number,
    description: {type: String, es_indexed:true},
    picture: String,
    vendor: {type: String, es_indexed:true},
    vendorId: String,
    vendorPicture: String,
    category: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);
```

What am trying to do is to fetch an item by Id and update:

```
app.put('/api/item/:id', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
    Item.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, 
        {title: req.body.title, description: req.body.description, price: req.body.price},
        function(err, item) {
            if(err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
            res.send('product updated');
        });
})
```

but, i got in the response and error and i can't figure out why, here is the erorr:

```
{"message":"Cast to string failed for value \"undefined\" at path \"title\"","name":"CastError","type":"string","path":"title"}
```

Comment: `log` your `req.body`, what do you see? For some reason it fails to cast it to a `String`

Comment: this the body `{ title: 'new title', description: 'search dress', price: 150 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you aren't getting anything in req.body.title and the casting didn't work for undefined. But then again, that's too basic, and you have probably checked it already, hard to tell from the code fragments. If not, I will start by console.logging the req.body.title and see what you need to do next...